# How to make this timer start itself soon as page loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can this particular code work on page load itself and even on refresh of page timer value remains ticking only when click submit it stops?

I guess we need to store the timer on localStorage and destroy storage on click submit?

```js
$(function() {

  // Some global variables
  var startTime = 0,
    elapsed = 0,
    timerId = 0,
    $timer = $("#timer");

  function formatTime(time) {
    var hrs = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60 / 1000),
      min = Math.floor((time - hrs * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 60 / 1000),
      sec = Math.floor((time - hrs * 60 * 60 * 1000 - min * 60 * 1000) / 1000);

    hrs = hrs < 10 ? "0" + hrs : hrs;
    min = min < 10 ? "0" + min : min;
    sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;

    return hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
  }

  function elapsedTimeFrom(time) {
    return formatTime(time - startTime + elapsed);
  }

  function showElapsed() {
    $timer.text(elapsedTimeFrom(Date.now()));
  }

  function startTimer() {
    // React only if timer is stopped
    startTime = startTime || Date.now();
    timerId = timerId || setInterval(showElapsed, 1000);
    localStorage.setItem('startTime');
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    // React only if timer is running
    if (timerId) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      elapsed += Date.now() - startTime;
      startTime = 0;
      timerId = 0;
    }
  }

  function resetTimer() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    $timer.text("00:00:00");
    startTime = 0;
    elapsed = 0;
    timerId = 0;
  }

  function editTimer() {
    pauseTimer();
    $timer.prop("contenteditable", true);
    $timer.css("border", "1px solid red");
  }

  function setElapsed() {
    var time = $timer.text(),
      arr = time.split(":");
    $timer.prop("contenteditable", false);
    $timer.css("border", "1px solid black");
    elapsed = parseInt(arr[0] * 60 * 60, 10);
    elapsed += parseInt(arr[1] * 60, 10);
    elapsed += parseInt(arr[2], 10);
    elapsed *= 1000;
  }

  function sendTime() {
    pauseTimer();
    // Set hidden input value before send
    $("[name='time']").val(formatTime(elapsed));
  }

  $("[name='start']").click(startTimer);
  $("[name='stop']").click(pauseTimer);
  $("[name='reset']").click(resetTimer);
  $timer.dblclick(editTimer);
  $timer.blur(setElapsed);
  $("form").submit(sendTime);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
</h1>
<form action="" method="post" ame="xyz">
  <input type="button" name="start" value="Start" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
  <input type="button" name="stop" value="Stop" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
  <input type="hidden" name="time" value="00:00:00">
</form>
```

Comment: Call startTimer() on document.ready()

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan and how to keep ticking the timer even if page refresh but when submit then destroy timer?

Comment: Try storing the start time in localStorage and retrieve when needed.

Comment: Then you should save the state of timer in local storage and fetch/save in the same local storage for all the variables.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan please help me out will really be greatful

Comment: Check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: If i could i sure would not ask for help mate :( really need ur expert help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the variable in localStorage not just the name

I have commented out the calls since they do not work in StackSnippets

Just uncomment them when you copy to your server.

```js
$(function() {

  // Some global variables
  var startTime = 0;
    elapsed = 0,
    timerId = 0,
    $timer = $("#timer");

  function formatTime(time) {
    var hrs = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60 / 1000),
      min = Math.floor((time - hrs * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 60 / 1000),
      sec = Math.floor((time - hrs * 60 * 60 * 1000 - min * 60 * 1000) / 1000);

    hrs = hrs < 10 ? "0" + hrs : hrs;
    min = min < 10 ? "0" + min : min;
    sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;

    return hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
  }

  function elapsedTimeFrom(time) {
    return formatTime(time - startTime + elapsed);
  }

  function showElapsed() {
    $timer.text(elapsedTimeFrom(Date.now()));
  }

  function startTimer() {
    // React only if timer is stopped
//    startTime = localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Date.now();
    startTime || Date.now(); // remove and uncomment above
    timerId = timerId || setInterval(showElapsed, 1000);
    // localStorage.setItem('startTime',startTime);
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    // React only if timer is running
    if (timerId) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      elapsed += Date.now() - startTime;
      startTime = 0;
      timerId = 0;
    }
  }

  function resetTimer() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    $timer.text("00:00:00");
    startTime = 0;
    elapsed = 0;
    timerId = 0;
  }

  function editTimer() {
    pauseTimer();
    $timer.prop("contenteditable", true);
    $timer.css("border", "1px solid red");
  }

  function setElapsed() {
    var time = $timer.text(),
      arr = time.split(":");
    $timer.prop("contenteditable", false);
    $timer.css("border", "1px solid black");
    elapsed = parseInt(arr[0] * 60 * 60, 10);
    elapsed += parseInt(arr[1] * 60, 10);
    elapsed += parseInt(arr[2], 10);
    elapsed *= 1000;
  }

  function sendTime() {
    pauseTimer();
    // Set hidden input value before send
    $("[name='time']").val(formatTime(elapsed));
    // localStorage.removeItem('startTime');
  }

  $("[name='start']").click(startTimer);
  $("[name='stop']").click(pauseTimer);
  $("[name='reset']").click(resetTimer);
  $timer.dblclick(editTimer);
  $timer.blur(setElapsed);
  $("form").submit(sendTime);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
</h1>
<form action="" method="post" ame="xyz">
  <input type="button" name="start" value="Start" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
  <input type="button" name="stop" value="Stop" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
  <input type="hidden" name="time" value="00:00:00">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function start_timer() {
  const pause_timestamp = localStorage.getItem('pause_timestamp');
  const start_timestamp = localStorage.getItem('start_timestamp');
  if (pause_timestamp) {
    localStorage.removeItem('pause_timestamp');
    localStorage.setItem('start_timestamp', Date.now() + (start_timestamp - pause_timestamp));
    return;
  }
  localStorage.setItem('start_timestamp', Date.now());
}

function reset_timer() {
  localStorage.removeItem('pause_timestamp');
  localStorage.setItem('start_timestamp', Date.now());
}

function pause_timer() {
  localStorage.setItem('pause_timestamp', Date.now());
}

function get_timer_ms() {
  const start_timestamp = localStorage.getItem('start_timestamp');
  const pause_timestamp = localStorage.getItem('pause_timestamp');
  if (!start_timestamp) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (pause_timestamp) {
    return pause_timestamp - start_timestamp;
  }
  return Date.now() - start_timestamp;
}

$("[name='start']").click(start_timer);
$("[name='stop']").click(pause_timer);
$("[name='reset']").click(reset_timer);

get_timer_ms() // timer value in ms
```